# How to make a simple progress bar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var barDisplay : float = 0;
 var pos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20,40);
 var size : Vector2 = new Vector2(60,20);
 var progressBarEmpty : Texture2D;
 var progressBarFull : Texture2D;

 function OnGUI()
 {

     // draw the background:
     GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y));
         GUI.Box (Rect (0,0, size.x, size.y),progressBarEmpty);

         // draw the filled-in part:
         GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (0, 0, size.x * barDisplay, size.y));
             GUI.Box (Rect (0,0, size.x, size.y),progressBarFull);
         GUI.EndGroup ();

     GUI.EndGroup ();

 } 

 function Update()
 {
     // for this example, the bar display is linked to the current time,
     // however you would set this value based on your desired display
     // eg, the loading progress, the player's health, or whatever.
     barDisplay = Time.time * 0.05;
 }
```

How do I make a geometry dash type progress bar in unity using OnGUI? I tried looking it up online, couldn't find it really. I am building a runner game something like Temple run and I want to show the player how much of the map is left to go.

Comment: Do you have to stick with the OnGUI()? Why not use UI Canvas which is easier to program?

Comment: Using UI image you can use the filling from 0 to 1 to gradually reveal the loading bar.

Comment: You really should use an UI slider, it is way easier and cleaner

Comment: Okey i will try to find how to do it with the UI if someone knows a good site comment please. Ty

Comment: Soo should i use a slider or an image?

Comment: All the tutorials i find online is only about health but I cant seem to find any that will explain distance. The only one i found is with OnGui()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For a progress bar**
You can use the Unity scrollbar object to make what you're looking for. There's a good tutorial on it [here](https://youtu.be/YMj2qPq9CP8). Essentially, you add a scrollbar object to your canvas, and then change the slider value from code.

**For scrolling textures**
If you want a scrolling texture on your progress bar, then you can animate an image placed on the slider. If you don't want to animate it by hand, then it's a little more complicated. Ideally you could set the texture offset of the image in code to get it to scroll, but after looking it up I don't think that Unity allows you to do that on non-3D objects.

If you still want it to scroll and don't want to make a hand-drawn animation for it, you might want to look into combining the UI mask component ([tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3gpXmo8zRo)), and the built-in 2D animation tools ([tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8)).

Comment: The problem is that the video shows scene loading. I cant find how to measure distance and then change the slider value depending on that distance.

Comment: If you know the maximum distance of the level, and the current distance of the level, then you can set the slider value to (currentDistance / maxDistance) in the Update function to get the progress of the player.

Comment: If you need to find out the distance between the start and the end of the level, make a "public Transform levelStart;", "public Transform player;" and a "public Transform levelEnd;" in your script, and assign them in the editor to the player object, and objects at the start of the level and end of the level.

Comment: Then in your code, you can find out "var currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(levelStart.position, player.position);", "var maxDistance = Vector3.Distance(levelStart.position, levelEnd.position);" and then "var sliderValue = currentDistance / maxDistance", and then set your slider value from the tutorial to "sliderValue".

Comment: I will try that in 1 hour or 2 and then update you back. Ty for your time

Comment: So i did everything but I get this error when trying to set the slider to the sliderValue(Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Slider') And i wanted to ask in which function do i put the whole code Update or?

Comment: Here is a link to the code (it should be in the update function because it needs to be re-updated every frame) https://www.codepile.net/pile/3eMzoZbm

Comment: Ty so much dude u are a hero. It all works now. Ty again.

Comment: Glad I could help :)